# How to link two combo boxes responsively with foreign keys

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, combobox

I have two tables one for Clients/Company and one for the Representatives for that company. I have written a method in WCF where I joined the two tables in order for them to work together. What should happen is, if I choose a Client/Company in the one combo box the second combo box should populate with the representatives in that company.

**WCF**

```
 public List<Represetative> GetRepByComp(string CompanyId)
        {
            TruckDb db = new TruckDb();
            List<Represetative> result = new List<Represetative>();

            Represetative x = new Represetative();
            Company o = new Company();

            var filter = (from reps in db.Represetatives
                          join company in db.Companies on reps.Id equals company.Id
                          where company.Id == int.Parse(CompanyId)
                          select reps);

            foreach (var item in filter)
            {
                result.Add(new Represetative()
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Name = item.Name
                });
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**WPF**

```
private async Task LoadClient(TruckServiceClient TSC, ComboBox combobox)
        {
            List<ClientItems> clientItems = new List<ClientItems>();
            foreach (var item in await TSC.GetCompaniesAsync())
                clientItems.Add(new ClientItems { Client = item.Name });
            combobox.ItemsSource = (clientItems.ToArray());
            combobox.IsEnabled = true;
            combobox.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }

        public class ClientItems
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Client { get; set; }

            public string RepId { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Client;
            }

        }
```

My issue is to create a method for the Representatives combo box in order for it to responsively work with the Client/Company Combo box, Any ideas?

Comment: ComboBox has a [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Listen to this on your client/company combobox instance. In the handler, get the **RepId** of the newly selected ClientItems instance and call your GetRepByComp() method to get the list of Represetative to populate your seconds combobox with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said Chris, subscribe to the SelectionChanged event :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxCompanies" 
      SelectionChanged="ComboBoxCompaniesSelectionChanged" />
```

And corresponding code behind :

```
private void ComboBoxCompaniesSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Client client = e.AddedItems[0] as Client;
    if (client != null)
    {
        TruckServiceClient tsc = null; // ...
        List<Representative> representatives = GetRepByComp(tsc, client.Id.ToString());
        comboBoxRepresentatives.ItemsSource = representatives;
    }
}
```

Regards